# cant get the local storage of flutter_webview

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm currently writing an app in Flutter that wraps around a Magento shop. I am trying to get the user from the flutter_webview local storage. does anyone know how I could achieve this?! is this possible at all?

I tried:

```
isLoggedIn = _controller
        .runJavaScriptReturningResult(
            'localStorage.getItem("mage-cache-storage")');
```

but I couldn't make it work

Comment: can you add in the code for the full implementation? Also i will say i have had much better experiences with injecting javascript using this library https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview